# Python removing specific values in array

Tags: python, arrays, list

As a part of a program I want to delete certain values from array. Filtering the values that I want works but I can't put them in the format I wish. I deliberately write a `-1` for every value I want removed. Is there a 2'd version on how to use this `result[result >= 0]`?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here, please add your code and I/O example.

Answer (score 0):

You could manage to do this with a list comprehension

Say you have your input array: in_array and a number you want to replace: num. You could do:

```
out_array = [n if n != num else -1 for n in in_array]
```

I hope this helps!